# WHERE IN with multiple columns in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift where I have two tables. A staging table where I COPY all data from S3 and a target table where everything should eventually be inserted.

Now I have query that should delete everything from the target table that is in the staging table so that I won't have duplicates.

```
DELETE FROM xschema.target
WHERE (col1, col2) IN 
(
SELECT col1, col2
FROM xschema.staging
)
AND col3 = 'de'
;
```

The query executes but it deletes everything where `col3 = 'de'` is true.
The `IN` condition of the statement always returns true.

For example: If I have in my target table the following values

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
aaa  | 1    | de   | 100
bbb  | 2    | de   | 200
ccc  | 1    | us   | 180
```

And in my staging table the following values:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
aaa  | 1    | de   | 100
ddd  | 1    | de   | 250
```

And I run the query above to delete all values in the target table from the staging table I get:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
ccc  | 1    | us   | 180
```

but I would expect:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
bbb  | 2    | de   | 200
ccc  | 1    | us   | 180
```

I have not found anything so far in the official documentation or here (at least not for redshift).
Any ideas on how to solve that?

*Edit: Added examples*

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Can you use exist this way? 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM xschema.staging Where staging.col1 = target.col1 and  staging.col2 = target.col2 )
AND col3 = 'some-value'

Comment: Thanks @Markov, that seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `EXISTS` :

```
DELETE 
FROM xschema.target t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM xschema.staging s WHERE s.col1 = t.col1 AND s.col2 = t.col2) AND
      col3 = 'de';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [Redshift started supporting](https://viooka.com/redshift-where-clause-multiple-columns-support/) this recently. Following query works without any issue on Redshift.

```
select * from inventory
where (INV_WAREHOUSE_SK, inv_item_sk) IN (select 1, 2);
```